# What does it mean by cakephp core developer?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have some confusion about CakePHP core developers.

Do CakePHP core developers develop/maintain `cakephp/lib/Cake/Core` files?

Or do they develop/maintain everything in `cakephp/lib`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As CakePHP is an open source project, development contributions can be made by anyone.

There is a group of developers that actively maintain the CakePHP project, termed "core developers".

As anyone can submit patches, contributions from outside this group come from the "community".

The project consists of everything in the [CakePHP GitHub repository](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.0), including the skeleton files in `app/`.

Comment: So is there any relationship with this directory cakephp/lib/Cake/Core and the core developers ?

Comment: Those are simply the core classes that the entire framework relies on. `Object` is the base class for every other object, `Configure` loads configuration files, `App` is responsible for loading files, `CakePlugin` loads plugins. The fact that those files and the core developers both feature the word "core" has no correlation. :)